# Shared Memory Functions

Tags: php

**This problem on only one server another server works is correct**

Help me

> Warning: shmop_delete(): can't mark segment for deletion (are you the
>   owner?) in /home/webuser/...
>
> Warning: shmop_open(): unable to attach or create shared memory
>   segment in /home/webuser/...
>
> Warning: shmop_write(): no shared memory segment with an id of [0] in
>   /home/webuser/...
>
> Warning: shmop_close(): no shared memory segment with an id of [0] in
>   /home/webuser/...

```
private function set($nameObj, $val)
{
    $val = serialize($val[0]);

    $obj_id = $this->get_obj_id($nameObj);
    $id = @shmop_open( $obj_id, "a", 0, 0);
    //$id = @shmop_open( $obj_id, "w", 0666, 0);

    if($id)
    {
        shmop_delete($id);
        shmop_close($id);
    }

    $id = shmop_open( $obj_id, "c", 0644, strlen($val));
    //$id = shmop_open( $obj_id, "c", 0666, strlen($val));

    shmop_write($id, $val, 0);
    shmop_close($id);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some code and explain where you getting this errors.

Comment: Yes. Both servers have php 5.6.32 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

**This script run correct via php cron.**

Shared Memory Functions did not work because I ran this hyperlink php script via browser.

Permissions to the memory area are allocated to another user than the one from which php works, this can happen if the browser starts the posting or ssh from the root